# How to make WHERE clause case insensitive in oracle sql database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, where-clause, case-insensitive

```
select * from table_Name where name ="red"
```

I need to fetch both "red" and "RED".

For example: I need to use both **upper** and **lower** in same statement.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **case insensitive** parameter at session `'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'`. There are two parameters at session level:

- `NLS_COMP`
- `NLS_SORT`

Let's see a demo:

**Normal scenario:**

```
SQL> with names as
    (
     select 'Vishnu' name from dual
    )
    -- Your query starts here
    select * from names where name='vIsHnU';

no rows selected
```

**Case insensitive approach:**

```
SQL> alter session set nls_comp='LINGUISTIC';

Session altered

SQL> alter session set nls_sort='BINARY_CI';

Session altered

SQL> with names as
    (
     select 'Vishnu' name from dual
    )
    -- Your query starts here
    select * from names where name='vIsHnU';

NAME  
------
Vishnu
```

**One more example:**

```
SQL> with names as
    (
     select 'red' name from dual union all
     select 'RED' from dual
    )
    -- Your query starts here
    select * from names where name='rEd';

NAME
----
red
RED
```

To **improve the performance**, you could also create a **case insensitive** `INDEX`.

For example:

```
create index names_ci_indx on names(NLSSORT(name,'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'));
```

Now, there are ways to improve performance of above transaction. Please read [**Oracle – Case Insensitive Sorts & Compares**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/)

Comment: alter session set nls_comp='LINGUISTIC';  alter session set nls_sort='BINARY_CI';added this two .. solved the issue..                                                                                                                                but got one problem.. suppose lets say the column name has some null values .. then the where condition  query is not working..

Comment: @VishnuK Okay, what do you mean by query is not working when not null? Are you getting any error or you want to exclude the NULL values? All you need to do is, just add an `AND your_column IS NOT NULL` if you want to remove NULLS.

Comment: it was just connection problem. but  thanks for the solution.. i just saw your blog .it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_Name where lower(name) ="red"
```

or

```
select * from table_Name where upper(name) ="RED"
```

This cannot use an index on `name`.  It might be appropriate to create a function based index on the expression used.